# Does $H \unlhd G$ imply $G/H$ is cyclic and therefore abelian?

Tags: group-theory, abelian-groups, cyclic-groups, normal-subgroups

I have a review question which wants me to show equivalency between the two ends of the question, and I came to the conclusion one way top show it is abelian would be to prove it is a cyclic group, but I am currently stuck on if my idea is right/what to do next. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: try $H = \{1_G\}$.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The converse is true: if $G/H$ is a cyclic group, then $G$ is abelian.

If we take an abelian group $G$ and non-abelian group $H$, then $G \times H$ is not abelian, even though $(G, 1) \trianglelefteq G \times H$.

Comment: Important  theorem : If  $A$  is a normal subgroup of $ B$  then $ B$ is isomorphic to $ A \times ( B/A)$

Comment: $S_3$ is nonabelian, but $S_3/A_3=C_2$ is cyclic.

Comment: @user254665 I don't think your statement is true in general. Take $B$ the free group with $n$ generators and $A$ its commutator subgroup.